# Listview Large Icon right click to open ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, right-click, contextmenustrip

In my project I have a `ListView` and I would like to open my `ContextMenuStrip` when I clicked right button in the large icon. I tried many things but I am unsuccessful. When I right click inside of `ListView` the `ContextMenuStrip` opens, but I want to see just when I right clicked the large icon.

[image]

Also I need to help about get the clicked icon's name (properties).

Comment: Did you try my code? I have updated it to work with (vertically scrolled LVs)

Comment: I tried but i am not sure i understand true :/ i couldnt worked your code in my listview item :/

Comment: What problems do you have? What code did you have before?

Comment: I would like to open ContextMenuStrip when i clicked the listview item and my items are created dynamically.

Comment: And I would like to learn how to use this dynamics items property

Comment: Yes, that's what you wrote in the question. But what probelms do you have with my code?? It uses a MouseDown (or if you prefer the Mouseup) event and makes use of a ContextMenuStrip. According to your question you already got all of it working except restricing the active area to the image, right?

Comment: Ohh now, i tired and change something its working but visual studio said sz isn't exist in your project, then how i can use this items do you know any tutorial about working with dynamics elements in listview. 

thank you so much.

Comment: sz has sneaked back in. It is the imageList1.ImageSize; I have updated the code. Please study the code to see how to reference the Item that you have clicked on (for example by using hi.Item) and how you can use its ImageIndex property to refer to the Image in the ImageList and its prpterties. It is all in the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution; please do put more work into it than I did..

```
// a class level reference, prepare it where you want..
ContextMenuStrip ms = new ContextMenuStrip();
```

You should either code the `MouseDown` or the `MouseUp` event:

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // disassociate from listview at first:
    listView1.ContextMenuStrip = null;

    // check for right button
    if (e.Button != System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) return;

    // get item info:
    ListViewHitTestInfo hi = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);

    // no item hit:
    if (hi.Item == null) return;

    // calculate the image rectangle:

    // this contains the unscrolled y coordinate:
    Point iloc = listView1.GetItemRect(hi.Item.Index).Location;
    // we combine it with the x-position:
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point (hi.Item.Position.X,  iloc.Y),
                                imageList1.ImageSize);
    // no image hit:
    if ( !r.Contains(e.Location) ) return;

    // maybe prepare or change the menue now..
    // here I display the image name from the keys array:
    ms.Items[0].Text = imageList1.Images.Keys[hi.Item.ImageIndex];
    ms.Location = e.Location;

    // associate with listview and show
    listView1.ContextMenuStrip = ms;
    ms.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following and let see wether it works or not...
    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
             if (listView1.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I tried that codes but when click somewhere in listview still the contentMenuStrip working. I just want to see contextMenuStrip when i clicked on item, and i want to get item properties for use.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView , e.Location);
            }
        }
    }`

Search the listview item on mouse click location. If it is there, show the menu.........